# How to save changes made on the pdf file using iText on ASP.NET?

Tags: .net, pdf, model-view-controller, itext, itext7

I am creating a web application that automates our work with PDFs.

I am currently testing iText7 on .NET to test if it fits our needs.

The main problem right now is saving modifications made to the file from a web page.

**Edit**

The scenario is following: we work with hundreds of PDF forms daily. We fill them up, modify, save, print, etc. The tool we are currently using for that is too complex. Thus, we want to simplify.

I tested that I can fill-up the form from the database and extract information from the fields. However, after filling up we may need to change some values in the form manually, save changes and write back to database.

The simplest solution is of course fill up, download the file, edit and save locally, re-upload the file onto the server, and then extract values out of the updated form and fill-up the database. It works, but it includes too much manual work such as downloading and re-uploading. My clients want it automated.

The other approach I tried was showing the pdf document in my web app, edit, and save all modifications with a button (on a web page). But couldn't make my button save the updated pdf document. I showed the file in MVC view like this:
`object data="@Url.Action("ShowPDFwithButton", "PdfTemplates", new { id = Model.FilledForm.id })"type="application/pdf">/object>`

The third approach I came up with is to add a new page with a 'Save' button on it to my filled form. I wanted that button in pdf itself to save my modifications. After that I would just extract the values of the saved form and update the database. I tried this code to add some functionality to my 'Save' button, but can't understand how to make it save changes and/or send the updated file to my action controller:`button.SetAction(PdfAction.CreateSubmitForm("/PdfTemplates/SavePdf/" + pdfMetadata.id, null,PdfAction.SUBMIT_EXCL_F_KEY));`

I would appreciate if anyone could help making the second and third approach work. Or maybe offer other approaches.

Comment: What do you mean by "modifications made to the file from a web page"? iText is not a web client technology. It may be used on the web server, but there it should be obvious, after all you have some output stream or file...

Comment: @mkl, the scenario is following: I fill up the pdf file from db automatically and show result on a web page. Now I want my users to be able edit it and save changes which would update a db. If itsn't itext's capability could you please suggest how can I achieve it?

Comment: I don't know any specific solution for that you can use as is.

Comment: @mkl, I thought about adding a new page with a 'save' button on it to my pdf. Is it possible to make that button do what I want? Save current status of a document.

Comment: Unfortunately you still are not clear about the kind of changes an user should be able to make. If you merely mean form fill-ins, then you can implement your use case by creating a Save button that sends the form contents to a target URL. Beware, though, that solution requires a full-featured PDF viewer. Numerous viewers only support read-only  *viewing*, only some support *filling in forms*, and not even all of those support *sending form values to target URL*.

Comment: @mkl, exactly. I was talking about form fill ins. Can you please share code sample on how to send form content to target URL?

Answer (score 0):

The OP clarified in comments what he meant by *saving modifications made to the file from a web page*:

> I was talking about form fill ins. Can you please share code sample on how to send form content to target URL?

Unfortunately I could only find an example for that for iText 7 for Java:

```java
public void manipulatePdf(String dest) throws IOException {
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SUBCRIBE), new PdfWriter(dest));
    PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);
    PdfButtonFormField submit1 = PdfFormField.createPushButton(pdfDoc, new Rectangle(90, 660, 50, 30), "POST", "post");
    submit1.setBackgroundColor(new DeviceGray(0.75f));
    submit1.setVisibility(PdfFormField.VISIBLE_BUT_DOES_NOT_PRINT);
    submit1.setAction(PdfAction.createSubmitForm(
            "/book/request", null,
            PdfAction.SUBMIT_HTML_FORMAT | PdfAction.SUBMIT_COORDINATES));
    // add the button
    form.addField(submit1);
    // create a submit button that posts the form as FDF
    PdfButtonFormField submit2 = PdfFormField.createPushButton(
            pdfDoc, new Rectangle(200, 660, 50, 30), "FDF", "FDF");
    submit2.setBackgroundColor(new DeviceGray(0.7f));
    submit2.setVisibility(PdfFormField.VISIBLE_BUT_DOES_NOT_PRINT);
    submit2.setAction(PdfAction.createSubmitForm(
            "/book/request", null, PdfAction.SUBMIT_EXCL_F_KEY));
    // add the button
    form.addField(submit2);
    // create a submit button that posts the form as XFDF
    PdfButtonFormField submit3 = PdfFormField.createPushButton(
            pdfDoc, new Rectangle(310, 660, 50, 30), "XFDF", "XFDF");
    submit3.setBackgroundColor(new DeviceGray(0.7f));
    submit3.setVisibility(PdfFormField.VISIBLE_BUT_DOES_NOT_PRINT);
    submit3.setAction(PdfAction.createSubmitForm(
            "/book/request", null, PdfAction.SUBMIT_XFDF));
    // add the button
    form.addField(submit3);
    // create a reset button
    PdfButtonFormField reset = PdfFormField.createPushButton(
            pdfDoc, new Rectangle(420, 660, 50, 30), "reset", "RESET");
    reset.setBackgroundColor(new DeviceGray(0.7f));
    reset.setVisibility(PdfFormField.VISIBLE_BUT_DOES_NOT_PRINT);
    // TODO DEVSIX-573
    reset.setAction(PdfAction.createResetForm(null, 0));
    form.addField(reset);
    // close the document
    pdfDoc.close();
}
```

*([SubmitForm.java](https://git.itextsupport.com/projects/I7JS/repos/samples/browse/publications/book/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/book/part3/chapter09/Listing_09_06_SubmitForm.java#30) example ported to iText 7 from chapter 9 of iText in Action, 2nd edition)*

As you see there are multiple options depending on what exactly shall be sent to the URL.

Comment: I've seen this code earlier. But I wasn't able to use it. The main reason I couldn't get how to send my form-field values to post action.

Comment: and as I told earlier my ultimate goal is to update the database with the values in the form in my document.

Comment: *But I wasn't able to use it.* - Why not? Because it is in Java?

Comment: *my ultimate goal is to update the database* - you tagged your question mostly with PDF related tags and not at all with database related ones. Furthermore you gave no information related to the database access. Thus, all looked like your problem was the "posting the PDF form data to the server" part, not the "how to write SQL update statements".

Comment: because it's not clear how do I send my file over to my action. I am sorry, I thought I did, apparently I forgot to add. Let me edit the question for more information.

Comment: Ok, that gives some background. But please also explain why you weren't able to use the code above; in my eyes that should be exactly what you need, you merely have to port it to a .Net language which in case of C# should be trivial...

Comment: I successfully added add 'Save' button on the document. It doesnt do anything in Chrome's PDF viewer, but works in IE. However, it just navigates to /PdfTemplates/SavePdf/id, but it doesn't pass the filled-form's latest state itself (edited pdf document). I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Comment: I am sorry for disturbing too much on this. But do you have any updates on my comment, or can you please tag if there is anyone else who could help me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're displaying an PDF object and want data from it to be posted back? That will not work I'm afraid. How would browser translate PDF's forms into POST data? But if this will run on modern browsers then maybe take a look at JavaScript viewers as Mozilla PDF.js? I can imagine that you can hack them one way or another to obtain data from PDFs forms and post it back via Ajax.